# encrypting mysql database used by spring mvc app

Tags: java, mysql, security, spring-mvc, encryption

A spring MVC app on a web server interacts with a MySQL database that is hosted on the same server.  The Spring MVC app needs to be able to search the database.

**Is there a way that I can encrypt the MySQL database to protect it from external malice, while also retaining the ability of the Spring MVC app to query the database?**  How?

I want to make sure that anyone other than the app will be unable to use the contents of the database, but I also need the app itself to be able to look up records by name, by id, etc.

Comment: What is your threat model (who, what, how)? How do you plan to protect the decryption key?

Comment: This question has multiple issues - first that it is not about programming; second that it is too broad because nothing about the application or how it will use the database is known; and third, any answer explaining any possible approach will be too long.  So, in the absence of any further information, take a look at [CryptDB](https://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/) that does what the title asks.

Comment: @manish I would like to use cryptdb with a spring mvc app.  From your link, it looks like cryptdb is a layer between MySQL and Spring MVC.  Can you point to a working sample app that accomplishes this?  In the past, I have examined the spring petclinic sample app.  It would be nice to see exactly how the config files need to be changed in a working example rather than to spend days stepping through resolving a series of unnecessary errors.

Comment: No changes are required to the app except to make sure that the JDBC URL points to the CryptDB proxy instead of the database directly. You will also need to make sure that all DDL commands are run through the CryptDB web interface instead of a regular MySQL client because CryptDB obfuscates database object names (tables, columns, indexes, etc.). There are no samples of integrating CryptDB with Spring (or any other framework for that matter) so you will have to try it out on your own. As I said, this is a very broad question so you should not expect for a ready-made solution to be available.

Comment: Also note that CryptDB is a homomorphic system, which means that it generally supports regular SQL features such as `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` and so on.  However, there is no guarantee that things will work fine under all conditions (that unfortunately is a limitation of homomorphic encryption).  Plus, you incur a performance penalty.  According to the CryptDB team, a minimum of 20% degradation should be expected compared to raw MySQL.

Comment: @manish I posted a separate question about how to set up CryptDB in an eclipse java project that uses maven.  Are you willing to help with it?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060445/calling-cryptdb-from-eclipse-java-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, MySQL does not support encryption of the entire database. You have will have to pick one of these solutions:

#### Encrypt certain columns

You probably don't need all of the data encrypted, only certain sensitive data. You can do this at the application level and only insert blobs into the database. This requires updating your code - aka not transparent.

#### Use an encrypted partition/disk

Another solution is to encrypt at the OS level. As long as the user permissions are set correctly, no malicious processes will be able to read the data when the system is running, and no one at all will be able to read it when the system is offline. This would require remembering to enter the password every time you start the machine/unlock the partition.

#### Use a database that supports encryption natively

[H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html) is one such database. It is a database written in pure Java for Java applications. This, unfortunately, will require data migration which can be painful depending on the contents.

#### Don't do anything at all

Take a look at the data you're protecting and your [threat model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model). Do you think encrypting the database will be worth your while? If your application is a simple, personal blog, then there's not much to protect except user's password hashes (you *are* hashing them, right?). If, on the other hand, you're storing medical data and are required to have it encrypted in some way, the first option will probably be the best way to go.

Comment: This answer does not include cryptdb, but I am marking it as accepted because it starts people thinking.  The comments above, after the OP, add other insights.